# Why do you have to link libraries AND set include directories

Tags: c++, include, static-libraries

Hey so i'm a little confused on why, in msVS++ 2010 you have to have include directories when all the headers and cpp files are inside the *static libray* or *static library project* in my case.

**I made the static library project with cmake, and the source file i was told to set it to is the same i'm now told to make the include directory... it seems like I have 2 of the same cpp and header files.. except ones included statically in my sollution... WHY?**

Comment: bit confused by some statements in the question: you say '2 of the same cpp and header files'. Does that mean you have A.cpp and A.hpp in one directory and a duplicate of them in another location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because VS++ while abstracting the underlying implementation does not hide it completely.

Include directories and libraries are targeted at different phase of the process, which are traditionally handled by different programs.  Include directories by the preprocessor, libraries by the linker.  Those programs are now called (or part of?) VC++, but its interface still shows the underlying structure.

There are systems which allows to mark the needed libraries in the source code (and thus in the header) by the use of pragmas.  Those have several disadvantages:

- non standard
- you can't as easily substitute libraries by another (say debug/instrumented/release, single thread/multi thread, ...)

Comment: @Mehrdad, Visual Studio I think -- I just copied the OP abbreviation.

Comment: Lol obviously it doesn't exist ("Visual Studio++"?), but I guess that makes it the OP's fault and not yours...

Answer (score 2):

Header files tell you *about* the functions you're calling.

Static libraries include the *code of the function* you're calling, but not information about *how* to call them.